# find equal rows between data frames, including NA as a value

Tags: r, dataframe, missing-data

I have two data frames:

```
df = structure(list(x = c(NA, NA, "b", "b", "b"), y = c("f", "f", 
"f", "g", "g")), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

df2 = structure(list(x = c(NA, NA, "a", "b", "b"), y = c("g", "f", 
"f", "g", "g")), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I would like to find the identical rows, when considering NA as a value.

```
df == df2
```

According to this, the second rows should be "TRUE". Instead we get NA. Although the logic for this is clear, can we modify `df == df2` so that these rows would be considered equal?

Comment: Try with `is.na(df)`

Comment: But how do I incorporate it into df == df2?

Comment: Try `rowSums(replace(df2, is.na(df2), "0") == replace(df, is.na(df), "0"))== 2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to `replace` the NA with a value not in the datasets, do the comparison, and check if all the rows are equal with `rowSums`

```
rowSums(replace(df2, is.na(df2), "0") == replace(df, is.na(df), "0"))== 2
#[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

---

Or without replacing, create a logical condition with `is.na`

```
rowSums((!is.na(df) & df== df2)|(is.na(df))) == ncol(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `paste` and compare, i.e.

```
do.call(paste, df) == do.call(paste, df2)
#[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```